# Layout spacing is off when using custom widgets vs. built-in widgets

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Consider the following screenshot of a running widget that was designed with Qt Designer:

[image: Dialog]

This is of a dialog with a `QGridLayout`. There are no special settings on the grid layout.

The widgets corresponding `Foo:` and `Baz:` are custom widgets, call them `QFoo` and `QBaz`, both also designed with Qt Designer, both inheriting from `QWidget`. They both use `QHBoxLayout`s, the top one of a `QLineEdit` and some buttons, the bottom of a `QSpinBox` and a `QComboBox`. The `Bar:` widget is just a `QLineEdit`.

Why are the widgets not aligned? Why is there more space for the custom ones than for the built-in ones?

Comment: Is the line edit part of Foo widget?

Comment: @Zen: `QFoo` contains a `QLineEdit` and some buttons, all in a `QHBoxLayout`. The `Bar:` widget is just a `QLineEdit` on its own (in the dialog, not in `QFoo` or `QBaz`)

Comment: Whoa, hold on, there's a lot of detail missing. 0. Where's your `.ui` file? You ask about code - show it, or else this is off topic - a lot of things can be wrong in your `.ui` file that could lead to this behavior. 1. How do you expose `QFoo` and `QBaz` to designer? Via a plugin? 2. How did you align the widgets in the second column? 3. Designer screenshots are not always accurate. You need to show a screenshot from the preview, or from an actual run of your code. Yes, you will need to make a self-contained test case if you don't wish to show your real widgets to us.

Comment: @KubaOber: Ah it actually was a screenshot of the run of the code. I see that there's not enough detail to answer this, I'll work on a better example when I take another crack at it.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using `QFormLayout` instead?

Comment: I don't see why they need to be aligned. QGridLayout just aligns direct children. And the layout of children of QFoo has nothing to do with QGridLayout. Maybe this will do what you want: `gridLayout->addWidget(lableFoo,0,0); gridLayout->addWidget(editFoo,0,1); gridLayout->addWidget(lableBar,1,0); gridLayout->addWidget(editBar,1,1);`